# GCP Cloud Run for Anthos - no healthy upstream

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, knative, google-anthos

I'm building microservices deployed to Cloud Run for anthos on GKE cluster in Google Cloud Platform.

I randomly get the error message "no healthy upstream" error message.

Maybe there are some problem related to GKE networking? I've seen questions related to "no healthy upstream but I couldn't find an answer that can solve this problem"

Please help

Comment: What's the cold start duration of your microservice?

Comment: it seems that your app is not working as expected or it taking sometime to start. did you test it locally? please elaborate more on your issue, provide more context, logs, screenshots. you cannot expect that you expect help when you don't provide enough explanation.